# Replacing/deleting some characters from a string which is in a List

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm supposed to ignore all the ",", ".", "-", and " **"** " from the string which is in List.
The list is like this: e.g.: `List("This is an exercise, which I have problem with", "and I don't know, how to do it., "text-,.")`

What I've just tried is map, but it doesn't want to compile. I also wanted to use `replace`, but decided not to do it, because I would be supposed to make `replace` for each character I want to ignore, so e.g. `replace(",", "").replace(".", "")` etc, wouldn't I?
Maybe is there a method where I can put all the characters I want to ignore together?

My code:

```
val lines = io.Source.fromResource("ogniem-i-mieczem.txt").getLines.toList
println(lines.map{
    case "," => ""
    case "." => ""
    case "-" => ""
    case "''" => ""
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple regex and `replaceAllIn()` should do it.

```
val inLst =
  List("This is an exercise, which I have problem with"
     , "and I don't know, how to do it."
     , "text-,.")

inLst.map("[-,.\"]".r.replaceAllIn(_, ""))
//res0: List[String] = 
// List(This is an exercise which I have problem with
//    , and I don't know how to do it
//    , text)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could apply a `regex` to that and replace them all at once. something like this:

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val regex = "\\.*,*-*\"*".r

val sampleText = "Hi there. This comma, should be gone. and dots and quotes \"as well."
val result = regex.replaceAllIn(sampleText, "")

println(s"result: $result")
// result: Hi there This comma should be gone and dots and quotes as well
```

applied to your sample code, it could look like this:

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val regex = "\\.*,*-*\"*".r

val result = io.Source
  .fromResource("ogniem-i-mieczem.txt")
  .getLines
  .toList
  .map { line => regex.replaceAllIn(line, "") }

println(s"Result: $result")
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers based on regex are the way to go but just as learning exercise note that we can conceptualise strings as sequence of characters which means we can treat them as collections so the usual suspects map/filter etc. could also work

```
lines map { _.filterNot { exclusionList.contains } }
```

where

```
val exclusionList = Set(',', '.', '-', '"')
```

Comment: Minor hint, exclusion list should be a `Set` for performance. - although regex is way more performant anyways :grimacing:

Comment: Is there a reason for using `{` and `}` rather than the more standard  `(` and `)` in this answer?

Comment: @Tim It is just subtle stylistic effect when using punctation-free https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#higher-order-functions. Otherwise you might end up having spaces after `(` which feels worng.

Comment: I managed to do it like this: `val linesToHisto = lines.map(line => line.replaceAll("[.,:-]", "").replace(" ", ""))`
I made a second replace because i didn't know how to add space to the regex in replaceAll